# smtp won't work in production, Unauthenticated even with credentials

Tags: smtp, go

I am having a hell of a time here. My code works on the local instance (OSX) with this config:

```
mail.host = smtp.gmail.com
mail.port = 25
mail.from = mysite.com
mail.username = email@gmail.com
```

But says it is unauthenticated in production (Ubuntu 12.0.1):

Here is my code (and you can find all of it at github.com/tanema/revel_mailer). The authentication error is thrown at the `c.Mail(username)` line.

```
func (m *Mailer) Send(mail_args map[string]interface{}) error {
  m.renderargs = mail_args
  pc, _, _, _ := runtime.Caller(1)
  names := strings.Split(runtime.FuncForPC(pc).Name(), ".")
  m.template =  names[len(names)-2] + "/" + names[len(names)-1]

  host, host_ok := revel.Config.String("mail.host")
  if !host_ok {
    revel.ERROR.Println("mail host not set")
  }
  port, port_ok := revel.Config.Int("mail.port")
  if !port_ok {
    revel.ERROR.Println("mail port not set")
  }

  c, err := smtp.Dial(fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", host, port))
  if err != nil {
    return err
  }

  if ok, _ := c.Extension("STARTTLS"); ok {
    if err = c.StartTLS(nil); err != nil {
      return err
    }
  }

  from, from_ok := revel.Config.String("mail.from") 
  if !from_ok {
    revel.ERROR.Println("mail.from not set")
  }


  username, username_ok := revel.Config.String("mail.username") 
  if !username_ok {
    revel.ERROR.Println("mail.username not set")
  }

  if err = c.Auth(smtp.PlainAuth(from, username, getPassword(), host)); err != nil {
       return err
  }

  if err = c.Mail(username); err != nil {
    return err
  }

  if mail_args["to"] != nil {
    m.to = makeSAFI(mail_args["to"]) //makeSAFI == make string array from interface
  }
  if mail_args["cc"] != nil {
    m.cc = makeSAFI(mail_args["cc"])
  }
  if mail_args["bcc"] != nil {
    m.bcc = makeSAFI(mail_args["bcc"])
  }

  if len(m.to) + len(m.cc) + len(m.bcc) == 0 {
    return fmt.Errorf("Cannot send email without recipients")
  }

  recipients := append(m.to, append(m.cc, m.bcc...)...)
  for _, addr := range recipients {
    if err = c.Rcpt(addr); err != nil {
      return err
    }
  }
  w, err := c.Data()
  if err != nil {
    return err
  }

  mail, err := m.renderMail(w)
  if err != nil {
    return err
  }

  if revel.RunMode == "dev" {
    fmt.Println(string(mail))
  }

  _, err = w.Write(mail)
  if err != nil {
    return err
  }
  err = w.Close()
  if err != nil {
    return err
  }
  return c.Quit()
}
```

I cannot figure out what the problem is; please help.

EDIT:

So I bit the bullet and signed up for google apps and set it all up with the domain and email. That lead me to believe that it was actually the MX records that I didnt change. So I tested out sending with my personal email again now that the MX records are set. No Luck. Any idea if I can setup the MX records for a personal gmail email so I dont have to pay for google apps?

Comment: Can you put the code into debug mode and print out the client and server headers?

Comment: I am sorry, how does one do that I have been searching for that exact thing so that I can see the values being sent by the smtp connection

Comment: @timanema You can use [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to inspect the packets.

Answer (score 3):

I developed a Gmail front-end and encountered a similar problem. Try the following:

1. Try using ssl://smtp.gmail.com and port 465.
2. log into your GMail account to see if it says something like 'An unauthorised third-party tried to accesss this account'. If you do, then grant your app permission to log you in.

Comment: Hey thanks that already happened while I was trying out different things, I clicked the link that it was me and it now it doesn't do anything. It doesn't even warn me.

Comment: I should clarify, the same setup that caused that warning now gives me a authentication error

Comment: Or port 587 for TLS. [source](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78775?hl=en)